# Postgres database crash when installing plpython

Tags: postgresql-9.1, plpython

I'm trying to install plpython in my Postgres 9.1 but it crashes the server:

```
postgres@dataserver1:~> /opt/postgres/9.1/bin/psql -d mydb
psql.bin (9.1.4)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=# create language 'plpythonu';
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

I have python 2.6.8 installed and the handler is correcty declared in the system:

```
select tmplname, tmplhandler, tmpllibrary from pg_pltemplate where tmplname like 'plpython%'

"plpythonu"  | "plpython_call_handler"  | "$libdir/plpython2"
"plpython2u" | "plpython2_call_handler" | "$libdir/plpython2"
```

And the handler is installed in the $libdir:

```
postgres@dataserver1:~> ll /opt/postgres/9.1/lib/postgresql/plpython*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6686333 Aug 17 14:27 /opt/postgres/9.1/lib/postgresql/plpython2.so
```

Any clues on this will be apreciated

**EDIT**

I've tried create extension plpythonu, plpython2u, and plpython3u and all of them crashes the server.

Reading a little in the docs I found the \dx command to list the installed extensions:

```
mydb=# \dx
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(1 row)
```

So I guess the only installed extension is plpgsql.

```
mydb=# select name, installed_version from pg_available_extensions where name like '%python%';
    name    | installed_version
------------+-------------------
 plpython2u |
 plpython3u |
 plpythonu  |
(3 rows)
```

and my extension directory:

```
postgres@dataserver1:/opt/postgres/9.1/share/postgresql/extension> ll *python*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 351 Aug 20 17:32 plpython2u--1.0.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 196 Aug 20 17:32 plpython2u.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 402 Aug 20 17:32 plpython2u--unpackaged--1.0.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 351 Jun  1 02:54 plpython3u--1.0.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 196 Jun  1 02:54 plpython3u.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 402 Jun  1 02:54 plpython3u--unpackaged--1.0.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 347 Aug 20 17:32 plpythonu--1.0.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 194 Aug 20 17:32 plpythonu.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 393 Aug 20 17:32 plpythonu--unpackaged--1.0.sql
```

**EDIT**

I'm running on Linux SuSE, but got your point.

In my postgres instalation, the pl-lang libraries are in .../postgres/9.1/lib/postgres. Inside it there are plpython2.so and plpython3.so

Checking the dynamic linked libraries of these files:

```
alfonso@dataserver1:/opt/postgres/9.1/lib/postgresql> sudo ldd plpython2.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5e945000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f64064df000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f64062da000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f64060d7000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6405e5e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6405ae9000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6406b2e000)
```

There is no reference to any python library, neither for plpython3.so

But I have installed python 2.6 and python 3.2. Note that I wish to install the extension for python 2.

And yes, CREATE EXTENSION is still crashing:

```
mydb=# create extension plpython2u;
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!> \q
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: As of PostgreSQL 9.1, most procedural languages have been made into "extensions", and should therefore be installed with **CREATE EXTENSION** not CREATE LANGUAGE. Direct use of CREATE LANGUAGE should now be confined to extension installation scripts. If you have a "bare" language in your database, perhaps as a result of an upgrade, you can convert it to an extension using CREATE EXTENSION langname FROM unpackaged.

To install PL/Python in a particular database:

from the shell command line use **createlang plpythonu dbname**

Caution

createlang is deprecated and may be removed in a future PostgreSQL release. Direct use of the CREATE EXTENSION command is recommended instead.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpython.html

**EDIT**

Step by step

Download the postgresql-9.1.5-1-windows.exe and install it.

First let's see what's already there.

```
mydb=# SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions
mydb-# WHERE name LIKE '%python%' ORDER BY name;
    name    | default_version | installed_version |                  comment

------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------
 plpython2u | 1.0             |                   | PL/Python2U untrusted procedural language
 plpython3u | 1.0             |                   | PL/Python3U untrusted procedural language
 plpythonu  | 1.0             |                   | PL/PythonU untrusted procedural language
(3 Zeilen)
```

**Nothing installed !!**

Looking at the lib folder and there is only.

....\PostgreSQL\9.1\lib\plpython3.dll.

So I must try to install plpython3u.

```
mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
ERROR:  unknown error »$libdir/plpython3.dll«
```

**There must be something wrong with plpython3.dll.**

Looking into **plpython3.dll** there is a reference to **python32.dll**.

```
......

Export Table:
  Name:                          plpython3.dll
  Time Date Stamp:               0x502B366A (15.08.2012 06:40:58)
  Version:                       0.00
  Ordinal Base:                  1
  Number of Functions:           9
  Number of Names:               9

  Ordinal   Entry Point   Name
        1   0x00001005    Pg_magic_func
        2   0x00001019    PyInit_plpy
        3   0x0000101E    _PG_init
        4   0x00001023    pg_finfo_plpython3_call_handler
        5   0x0000100F    pg_finfo_plpython3_inline_handler
        6   0x0000100A    pg_finfo_plpython3_validator
        7   0x00001028    plpython3_call_handler
        8   0x00001014    plpython3_inline_handler
        9   0x0000102D    plpython3_validator

Import Table:
  libintl-8.dll
    Import Adress Table:                0x00016628
    Import Name Table:                  0x0001617C
    Time Date Stamp:                    0x00000000
    Index of first forwarder reference: 0x00000000

    0x000169E4        28   libintl_dngettext
    0x000169D0        27   libintl_dgettext

  **python32.dll**
    Import Adress Table:                0x0001686C
    Import Name Table:                  0x000163C0
    Time Date Stamp:                    0x00000000
    Index of first forwarder reference: 0x00000000
  ....
```

- I download and install python-3.2.3.msi. I found only **python3.dll**
- Copy the python3.dll to ....\PostgreSQL\9.1\lib  and rename it to
  **python32.dll**

**Back in SQL Shell i typed**

```
mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u FROM unpackaged;
```

I got the message

```
CREATE EXTENSION
```

**Looking for the result with:**

```
mydb=# SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions
mydb-# WHERE name LIKE '%python%' ORDER BY name;
```

**There it is** the installed_version 1.0 of **plpython3u**

and i also can see it in PgAdmin III

Hope that helps !

[image: Postgresql 9.1]

**EDIT:**

Try it manually

Step 1

> mydb=# CREATE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpython2u;

Step 2

> mydb=# COMMENT ON PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpython2u IS 'PL/Python2U untrusted procedural language';

Step 3

> mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION plpython2u FROM unpackaged;

Tested with Python 2.6.5

Comment: Thanks for all the support @moskito-x.
Create extension gives me this error: "language "plpython2u" does not exist"
This message is an insight from where I can look for, since it seems that nobody else is having this problem.

Comment: Yep. That was the original problem:

mydb=# CREATE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpython2u;
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!> \q

Comment: Nop. Not found any path to python's executable. Maybe thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Postgres 9.0 with Python 2.7 installed on WIN 8.1 64-bit.
FYI: Here is how I managed to solve the
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/plpython.dll"
when running 
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu; in pgAdmin

- After installing Postgresql 9.0 from EnterpriseDB the path C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\lib should contain the file "plppython.dll"
- Checking this file with a program such as dependency walker reveals that it is missing a python26.dll
- If you look in you C:\windows\system32 catalog you should find a file python27.dll
- Create a copy of python27.dll -> python26.dll
- Make sure you C:\windows\system32 is in your PATH variable
- Run CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu; im pgAdmin