# postgresql 9 plpython2.dll not found

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

I am trying to enable PL/Python2 in my postgresql database. My setup is as follows

```
windows 7 64-bit 
postgresql 9.2 64-bit
```

In the \lib folder i have plpython3.dll but no plpython2.dll which I need as a function I need to use was written in Python2.

I found a plpython2.dll on another forum but it was a 32-bit version (I used dependency walker to test what the dll required)

I have since tried postgresql 9.0 which only has plpython.dll (which when I follow these instructions [Postgres database crash when installing plpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010344/postgres-database-crash-when-installing-plpython)) and then I thried postgresql 9.1 and the plpython3.dll appeared.

In the documentation it states that "Users of binary packages might find PL/Python in a separate subpackage." But I cannot find any anywhere.

I have the correct Python in my PATH environment variable and have even copied the python26.dll into the \lib folder.

Does anyone know where I can find the plpython2.dll?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is extensive discussion at http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2878.page

I am not sure I would try the unverified DLL download attached to one post, and certainly not on a production server.  My sense from reading the link is that pl/python2 is NOT SUPPORTED on Windows PostgreSQL 9.x because these are built against Python 3.x

I could be missing something however.

Comment: thanks for your comment unfortunately that link to the DLL is a 32bit version and I tried on both 32 and 64bit and neither would register. Will now need to look at the python script to see if it can be changed to python 3.x. Many thanks

Comment: To be specific, this version of PostgreSQL requires Python version 3.2