# PostgreSQL: Create extension plpythonu query not working on Ubuntu 19.10 and PostgreSQL 10.10

Tags: python, database, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-19.04

I'm using `my_db=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpythonu SCHEMA pg_catalog VERSION '1.0';` query in **PostgreSQL 11.5** installed on **Ubuntu 19.10** to create *plpythonu extension*. But I faced following error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory
```

For installing *plpythonu package* I used `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-plpython3` command and it successfully installed. Then, I checked `/usr/share/postgresql` directory and there are **10** and **11** directories in my case. I googled for error and I found [PostgreSQL: how to install plpythonu extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010344/postgres-database-crash-when-installing-plpython) and [Postgres database crash when installing plpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091390/postgresql-how-to-install-plpythonu-extension) posts and followed the answers, but they didn't worked in my case. Also, I read about it in documentation in here [Chapter 43. PL/Python - Python Procedural Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpython.html) but still could not find a solution for solving the error and I can not create the plpythonu extension in database. Now, I wonder if I should remove or uninstall anything or there is something wrong with my PostgreSQL? Please guide me with steps I should follow to create the extension.

Comment: "ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10"  You don't seem to be connected to a version 11 PostgreSQL server.

Comment: "psql" is not the database server, it is a client program.  The version of "psql" does not need to match the version of the server it is connected to.

Comment: Following command shows the PostgreSQL version is different than psql version and your right.`apps_mod=# SELECT version();

 version
                                                                 
 PostgreSQL 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)`. Then with above version of PostgreSQL what is wrong with database and creating plpythonu extension? What should I do to fix the above error?

Answer (score 2):

looks you installed wrong version plpython3u on you postgresql 10.

You can try:

**OS level installation:**

1. update local repositary by

   apt update
2. search supported plpython version for your database by

   apt-cache search plpython
3. check the result, find right package for postgres 10 plpython3u, below is example list in my debian based postgres dockers container

> postgresql-plpython3-10 - PL/Python 3 procedural language for
> PostgreSQL 10  postgresql-plpython3-10-dbgsym - debug symbols for
> postgresql-plpython3-10  postgresql-plpython3-11-dbgsym - debug
> symbols for postgresql-plpython3-11  postgresql-plpython3-12 -
> PL/Python 3 procedural language for PostgreSQL 12
> postgresql-plpython3-12-dbgsym - debug symbols for
> postgresql-plpython3-12  postgresql-plpython3-13 - PL/Python 3
> procedural language for PostgreSQL 13  postgresql-plpython3-13-dbgsym
>
> - debug symbols for postgresql-plpython3-13

4. install the right package pg10 + plpython3u and not debug version by

   apt install postgresql-plpython3-10

**Postgresql Level installation & Configuration**

1.connect to your postgresql 10 DB and create extension by

> =# create extension plpython3u;
> CREATE EXTENSION

2. check readness by

> =# \dx
> List of installed extensions
> Name    | Version |   Schema   |                Description
> ------------+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------  plpgsql    | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
> plpython3u | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/Python3U untrusted procedural
> language (2 rows)

3. run first plpython3u function pymax by:

   ```
   <DB name>=# CREATE FUNCTION pymax (a integer, b integer)
    RETURNS integer
    AS $$
    if a > b:
        return a
    return b
   ```

   $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

if eveything is OK, you has got first plpython3u function. Enjoy.

Note: you may need install python3 first by apt install python3